# Best approach for storing large data collection from json api in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to make an offline capable app that can fetch about 10,000 objects (est. 10mb data) from a json api and store them locally so they can be used when there is no internet connection.

I have looked at react-native-sqlite-storage (https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage). Is that the best option or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, I have found below open source SQLite plugins which are available for React Native apps:

- https://github.com/Siminov/hybrid
- https://github.com/almost/react-native-sqlite
- https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage
- https://github.com/jbrodriguez/react-native-android-sqlite
- https://github.com/ramsundark5/react-native-sqlite3
- https://github.com/remobile/react-native-sqlite

If you just want to store your data, then I would recommend to use file storage. But if you want to store data in form of RDBMS then you can use one of the above plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is also now a  [pouchDB (NoSQL)](https://github.com/carbureted/react-native-pouchdb) react-native implementation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since my question, Realm has begun supporting react native and it fits my needs perfectly - build specifically for mobile, very fast and easy to work with and it performs really well.